# Google App Engine git push-to-deploy insufficient privilages

Tags: git, google-app-engine

Following the [directions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/push-to-deploy), I have

- Created a project in my Cloud Console
- Enabled push-to-deploy
- Got an auth token
- Put `machine code.google.com login my-address@gmail.com password 1/blahblahsecuritytoken` in my `~/.netrc` file
- Cloned the provided URL

But apparently I have a problem actually trying to deploy:

```
$ git push appengine master %# 1  17:35:44
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 286 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Scanning pack: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Storing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Processing commits: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Deploying...
remote: You do not have sufficient privileges to deploy, consider recreating your auth token.
To https://code.google.com/id/my-url-was-here/
   109e2cd..d1caea5  master -> master
```

Yet it actually accepts my changes in git! I've re-created my auth token at least once, with no success. Google ironically turns up no results when I search for `google app engine git push "do not have sufficient privileges"`.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a temporary problem on Googles side. Deployment started working immediately after a post on https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9917.

It took Google a few days to fix the problem.